# Windows Hotspot disconnects the Windows itself from Internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-11, wireless-hotspot

I'm using a local network to connect to the internet. I connect my Windows 11 laptop directly using a Lan cable to the network.
After turning Windows Hotspot feature on, My Android phone has access to the internet but the laptop it self disconnects from the internet!
What causes this problem?

Comment: Make sure you are just using one connection at one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem introduced by the Windows update of
[June 14, 2022—KB5014699 (OS Builds 19042.1766, 19043.1766, and 19044.1766)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/june-14-2022-kb5014699-os-builds-19042-1766-19043-1766-and-19044-1766-5c81d49d-0b6e-4808-9485-1f54e5d1bb15).

According to the post
[When I turn on Windows 10 mobile hotspot, I lose internet connection on my PC](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/when-i-turn-on-windows-10-mobile-hotspot-i-lose-internet-connection-on-my-pc.3766809/) ,
the solution is either to undo this update or, if System Restore is
enabled, rollback Windows to about the 13th of June 2022.